# Delete several tables in QGIS DB manager

Tags: qgis, database

I have a lot of tables in a PostGIS-Database and I want to delete most of them. In the QGIS DB manager, I am able to delete one by one (right-click -  delete). However, that's quite annoying. How to delete several tables in the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By being very cautious and aware that this will erase all tables and their configurations, triggers, attached views, you can execute the following SQL, then copy the result and execute it:

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || ' CASCADE;' AS drop_script
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
AND table_name NOT IN ('spatial_ref_sys');
```

You can adapt the script in the `WHERE` clause to :

```
WHERE table_name IN ('my_table_to_erase1', 'my_table_to_erase2')
```

Comment: I get the following syntax error:  `syntax error at or near "'.'" (LINE 1) `,

                                              ^

Comment: I checked again my code and it works perfectly ...

Comment: In case my schema has the name table_schema and the table table_name, then how exactly is the implemenation, without the spacholders like ||? I tried it like this and got the error: `SELECT 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' table_schema'.' table_name ' CASCADE;' AS drop_script
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
AND table_name NOT IN ('spatial_ref_sys');`

Comment: the pipes `|` are for concatenation between many data, here between text and database values. If you delete it, it won't work.

Comment: OK, sorry, of course! I considered the pipes as a kind of wildcard - as you see, I'm a bloody beginner, so thanks for you patience! Now, it, works perfect.

Comment: Pipes are used also under QGIS expression dialog for select or update. If my solution works, please validate it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use DBeaver to administer your PostGIS/PostgreSQL database... DB Manager is nice, but since you have the database, you should use a more robust and proper tool.

With DBeaver, since you don't want to delete *all* your tables, you should be wary of using any SQL script that attempts to delete tables in bulk - that is dangerous. (There are, however, ways to isolate tables using SQL scripts, but again, be  very careful).

My preferred way is to use DBeaver.

Here, you can open a schema, view the tables, interactively select which ones you want to delete, and right-click > delete the tables. This is a safe way to accomplish a bulk delete.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for the answer. So I now have two working solutions, more than I expected. Thanx to both contributors, appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @babel good stuff!