# Delete multiple layer at once in geopackage QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage, remove

Is there a way to delete more than one layer at the same time in a geopackage file once I have opened the connection in QGIS? I am only able to delete them one by one...very time consuming.

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/324851/88814

Answer (score 6):

You can select all of them in the browser panel and click `Delete selected layers` in the context menu. Unfortunately, you will have to confirm the deletion of each layer.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

GeoPackage is a SQLite database and it is using standard SQL. Tables are removed with DROP TABLE https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_drop_table.asp. So under the hood the tables are always dropped one by one. However, the user interface can offer convenience methods, or you can write a batch file. Windows example

```
drop_many.bat
=============
ogrinfo -sql "DROP TABLE table_1" my_geopackage.gpkg
ogrinfo -sql "DROP TABLE table_3" my_geopackage.gpkg
ogrinfo -sql "DROP TABLE table_4" my_geopackage.gpkg
```

Run "drop_many" from the GDAL command window and three tables will be dropped. Be careful when writing the commands, there is no rollback!

Notice that the DROP TABLE that is implemented into GDAL updates also the metadata tables https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html

> Starting with GDAL 2.2, the “DROP TABLE layer_name” and “ALTER TABLE
> layer_name RENAME TO new_layer” statements can be used. They will
> update GeoPackage system tables.

By using DROP TABLE with a standard SQLite client it is easy to put the GeoPackage in disorder.